# Squid / XulRunner: HTTPS forbidden page

Tags: c#, xul, squid, geckofx

I have a custom browser using GeckoFx (C# implementation of XulRunner) coupled with Squid as content filter. It runs fine for blocking http pages (i get the HTML block page from squid instead of the forbidden website), but for HTTPS pages, i get an internal error message, as squid is refusing the CONNECT to the HTTPS forbidden website). I'd like a clear blocking page instead.
In Xul, the error page is a page called chrome://global/content/commonDialog.xul , but i see no way to "look" into it to check the error message and react. I can"t just replace that commonDialog.xul page because it's also used for printing, authenticating, etc.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What is the exact message you're seeing?